# Как правильно получить данные из firebase в приложении flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, dart, flutter

Пишу приложение, которое обращается к firebase. Там json вида:

```
{
    "dashboardItemType": 0,
    "dashboardItemTitle" : "ЧИСЛЕННОСТЬ",
    "indicator1" : 1995,
    "indicator1Title" : "мужчин",
    "indicator2" : 823,
    "indicator2Title" : "женщин",
    "mainIndicator" : 2818,
    "mainIndicatorUnit" : "чел."
  }
```

Мой запрос к базе данных выглядит так:

```
        database
            .reference()
            .child('dashboardList')
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          String data = snapshot.value.toString();
          print(data);
          return data;
        })
```

При этом все работает и возвращает строку вида

```
{mainIndicator: 2818, indicator1Title: мужчин, dashboardItemTitle: ЧИСЛЕННОСТЬ, indicator2Title: женщин, dashboardItemType: 0, indicator1: 1995, indicator2: 823, mainIndicatorUnit: чел.}
```

Все было бы прекрасно, но в этой строке НЕТ кавычек ""!!! Без них система матерится и не хочет десериализировать эту строку в инстанс объекта!

[image: это DataSnapshot]

Если я пробую сделать из DataSnapsot.value --> Map появляется ошибка несовместимости

```
I/flutter (30957): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (30957): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (30957): _FutureBuilderState<DataSnapshot>#88f81):
I/flutter (30957): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Просьба ликвидировать мою безграмотность в этом вопросе! Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Получаем сообщения 
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages').orderByChild('date');
}

//Отправляем сообщения
void _sendMessage(String text) {
  _db.reference().push().set({
    "text": text,
    "date": DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch
  });
}

...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
Expanded(
  //Формируем список для показа
  child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
    sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
    query: _db,
    itemBuilder: (_, snapshot, animation, index) {
      return ChatMessage(
        napshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
      }))
}
...
//Показываем сообщения из сформированного списка
class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.snapshot, this.animation});

  final Animation animation;
  final DataSnapshot snapshot;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor:
            CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.decelerate),
        child: Container(
            child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
                  Text(snapshot.value['text'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
          ]))
        ])));
  }
}
```